# Problema no bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Estou tendo problema na *index.html*, porém não sei como resolver. 
Era pro **Mizuxe** aparecer à esquerda mas acontece o oposto.

Já meus itens: *Home; About; Meet; The; Authors* e *Contact* desaparecem.

Meu *index.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Starter</title>
</head>
<body id="home">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top py-4">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="img/mlogo.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""> 
        <h3 class="d-inline align-middle">Mizuxe</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#authors" class="nav-link">Meet The Authors</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/navbar-fixed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Para facilitar o entendimento, segue o **formato errado**:
[image: Errado]

e **formato desejado:**
[image: certo]

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa colocar a *logo* antes do botão, e a classe `navbar-expand-lg` na tab `<nav>`. Além de incluir os atributos abaixo no botão do menu:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light fixed-top py-4">
 <div class="container">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
     <img src="img/mlogo.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""> 
     <h3 class="d-inline align-middle">Mizuxe</h3>
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#authors" class="nav-link">Meet The Authors</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Resolvido. Achei que era no bootstrap.

Comment: @Apach3 Blz! Se achou a resposta útil, marque ✔ para que futuramente possa ajudar outros com o mesmo problema. Abs!